How to get the service to which the ECS task belongs
I am using AW Lambda, which consumes ECS task events. Based on task state change event I need to get the corresponding service (ECS service name).
Right now I use Task Group to retrieve it, but I've found that it does not work for all of the tasks (some tasks have groups with 'family' prefix). Also going through all services and checking their tasks is not an option (there are a lot of services and Lambda has a few seconds timeout).
I saw that apparently task definition ARN contains service name, but I am not sure that it is the rule for AWS ARN generation (could not find any docs), but rather some custom definition ARN generation (which won't apply to all of the tasks). What would be the best approach in this situation?

can you show us or link us to the stack change event?

Task ARN format is arn:${Partition}:ecs:${Region}:${Account}:task/${ClusterName}/${TaskId} as documented here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonelasticcontainerservice.html#amazonelasticcontainerservice-resources-for-iam-policies it has the cluster, not the service in it.

Looking at the output from some aws ecs describe-tasks calls, the only way to get the service seems to be from the task's group attribute. But you say that doesn't work if the task has a family defined? Is the service name no longer in there at all, or do you just need to adjust your parser to handle the possibility of the family being in there? Can you provide an example in your question of one that doesn't work?

@MarkB, by default group has format like "service:{actual_service_name}", but it can be set customly, i see staff like this in group field : "family:{cluster}-{service_group}", this group will be the same for tasks corresponding to any service in the group i guess (but it is not the name of a real service , it is like grouping of several of actual services)

I haven't tried this, so not an answer, but describe_tasks also provides the startedBy attribute, which is supposed to be the deployment ID of the service (which probably means iterating services to find the one with that deployment ID).

Turns out the task which have a corresponding service have a group with this pattern : "service:{service_name}", and the tasks with the group starting with "family" are standalone tasks

Blockquote
By default, standalone tasks use the task definition family name (for example, family:my-task-definition) as the task group name if a custom task group name isn't specified. Tasks launched as part of a service use the service name as the task group name and can't be changed.
Blockquote


Good find! You can accept your own answer.
